# How to get coordinates of corners from GPUImageHarrisCornerDetector?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, gpuimage

I want to detect rectangles and its corners via harris corner detector. It contains a block with corners:

```
            filter.cornersDetectedBlock = { (cornerArray:UnsafeMutablePointer<GLfloat>, cornersDetected:UInt, frameTime:CMTime) in
```

The problem is, cornerArray is of type GLfloat and it returns a value between 0 and 1. I don't know how to create something like CGPoint with x and y values. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specifics, but in general you have to interpolate.

I assume that you're getting back values for x and y that both range from 0 to 1, where 0 is the left/bottom edge, and 1 is the right/top edge?

You just need to lay out a ratio and convert from one coordinates system to the other.

0...1000
is to 
0...1

```
.5       x
----  = ----
 1      1000

x * 1 = 0.5 * 1000
x = 0.5 * 1000 / 1
x = 500
```

So if you get a value 0.5 it would be halfway between 0 and 1000. (1000-0) * 0.5. If your pixel rectangle has an origin of 0,0, you'd just multiply your 0..1 x value by your width and your 0..1 y value by your pixel height. If the pixel origin is not 0 then you need to add the origin.